# keep in memory a data of an API with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, local-storage, react-router-dom

I try to keep in mind by refreshing the page the price of a product. The default value of this price comes from data retrieved from an API and I would like with an input text to change this price and keep it at the refresh of the page. I tried with localStorage so it retrieves the new price in the console application but when I refresh the page the price remains the default one and not the new price put in the input

I leave you my code below and I thank you in advance for your explanations

ProductsDetails :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../css/ProductsDetails.css'
import {AiOutlineArrowLeft} from "react-icons/ai";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


export default class ProductsDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
          id: this.props.match.params.id, 
          price: 0
        };
    }

    updatePrice = (e) => {
      localStorage.setItem('price', e.target.value)
      this.setState({
        price: e.target.value
      });
    };
    submitHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const {
        match: {
          params: { id }
        }
      } = this.props;
      this.props.updatePrice(id, this.state.price);
      
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const price = localStorage.getItem('price')
        this.setState({price});
    }
  
    render() {
      const {
        match: {
          params: { id }
        },
        products
        
      } = this.props;

      const listProduct = products.find((product) => product.id === Number(id))
      if (!listProduct) return null;
  
      return (
        <div className="products__details">
          <Link to="/">
            <AiOutlineArrowLeft className="nav__arrow" />
          </Link>
          <h1 className="details__title">{listProduct.title}</h1>
          <div className="details__align--desk">
            <div className="details__img">
              <img
                className="product__img"
                src={listProduct.image}
                alt="Affichage du produit"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="products__align--desk">
              <h2 className="product__title">Description</h2>
              <p className="product__description">{listProduct.description}</p>
              <h2 className="product__title">Price</h2>
              <form className="form__price" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <input
                name="price"
                  className="input__price"
                  type="text"
                  defaultValue={Number(listProduct.price).toFixed(2)}
                  onChange={this.updatePrice}
                />
                <p>
                  Price (including VAT):{" "}
                  {Number(listProduct.price * 1.2).toFixed(2)} €
                </p>
                <br />
                <input
                  className="btn__update"
                  type="submit"
                  value="Update product"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="category__align--desk">
              <h2 className="product__title">Category</h2>
              <p className={`${listProduct.category==="men's clothing" ? "category__orange" : "category__green"} product__category`}>{listProduct.category}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Products :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/Products.css';
import './ProductsDetails'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Products extends Component {
  render() {
    const listsProducts = this.props.products.map((listProduct) => {
      return (
        <tbody className="products__body" key={listProduct.id}>
          <tr>
            <td><Link to={{pathname: "/products-details/" + listProduct.id}}>{listProduct.title}</Link></td>
            <td><p className={`${listProduct.category==="men's clothing" ? "category__orange" : "category__green"}`}>{listProduct.category}</p></td>
            <td>{Number(listProduct.price).toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>
              {Number(listProduct.price * 1.2).toFixed(2)} €
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      );
    });

    return (
      <main className="products">
        <h1 className="products__title">Products management</h1>
        <table cellSpacing="0">
          <thead className="products__head">
            <tr>
              <th className="table--title">Product name</th>
              <th className="table--title">Category</th>
              <th className="table--title">Price</th>
              <th className="table--title">Price (including VAT)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {listsProducts}
        </table>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

App :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import './css/Products.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Oval} from 'react-loading-icons'
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
import Products from './Components/Products';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,} from 'react-router-dom';
import ProductsDetails from './Components/ProductsDetails';

export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const updatePrice = (id, price) => {
    setProductsData((productsData) =>
      productsData.map((product) =>
        product.id === Number(id)
          ? {
              ...product,
              price: Number(price)
            }
          : product
      )
    );
};
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=7").then((res) => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
    setProductsData(res.data);
    },
    (error) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setError(error);
    }
    );
  }, []);
  if (error) {
    return <div>Erreur : {error.message}</div>
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>
    <Oval stroke="#564AFF"/>
    <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navigation/>
        <Switch>        
          <Route
            path="/products-details/:id"
            render={(props) => (
              <ProductsDetails 
                products={productsData}
                updatePrice={updatePrice}
                {...props}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/"> 
            <Products products={productsData}
            /> 
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to initialize the input then you should use defaultValue, but if you want to use state to change the value then you need to use value and that is problem here, try switching to value instead of defaultValue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i change the `defaultValue` in `value`, I can't even modify the input anymore

Comment: with defaultValue you can change the input without using onChange but with value to change you need to use onChange. So if you are using onChange as mentioned in the code above you should be able modify it

Comment: I have an onChange in the input but It takes into account the state price except that in my value it is the price of the API that I retrieved that is displayed because I want that at the start it is this price that is displayed but after that I can modify it I don't know how to do it

Comment: Doing price change in ProductDetails component will change the price for every product, first you need to handle the changed price in parent component from where this child component is getting props. Otherwise you will need to use hooks like useReducer or redux for state management. Updating price using localStorage is not a good practice, you should submit data to the backend and retrieve the updated data from there.